# How can we add more than one set of scale values around a polar chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is a photo I modified for reference of what I am looking for:
[image]

I need to add more than one set of scale values around a polar chart Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `parallel-coordinates` module, along with the following to your `chart` config:

```js
chart: {
  parallelCoordinates: true,
  parallelAxes: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    tickAmount: 6
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this will label *every* y-axis.

Based on the following:

- https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/polar
- https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/parallel-coordinates-chart

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        parallelCoordinates: true,
        parallelAxes: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          tickAmount: 6
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 45,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        tickInterval: 2
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 45
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Line',
        data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/11.2.0/highcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/11.2.0/highcharts-more.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/11.2.0/modules/accessibility.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/11.2.0/modules/parallel-coordinates.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```